# Search bar with SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, searchbar

Hello  I need to make a searchbar encapsulated into a toolstrip bar with smartgwt or even gwt
No hints available on net but I really need to do it

Comment: I also need the same thing, did you manage to find it or create one? I need to have a search bar on top of the page which enables the user to search the website.

Answer (score 0):

GWT does not contain any such build-in method. You need to build the search bar manually by coding.

But SmartGWT definitely contains such built-in functionality, where you'll get searchbox on top of every column.

For a working example, please have a look at the following link:

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_sortfilter_filter